# Как сделать красивый вывод HTML из PHP-скрипта?

Tags: php, html

На проекте понадобилось сделать, чтобы HTML-код был идеальным. А это значит, что каждый отступ должен быть такой, какой должен быть. И у меня возникли две проблемы:

1. Когда я делаю в коде отступ для php-кода, то этот отступ потом смещает тег `<tr>`.
2. Пришлось в **echo** добавить множество пробелов, чтобы правильно выводились остальные теги `<tr>` и теги `<td>`. Как по мне, выглядит это ужасно.

[image: php и html код]

Сразу говорю, что я сторонник не быстрых решений (как у меня в п.2), а правильных. Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Comment: Как вариант - собирать весь html в переменную, а потом прогнать её форматтером и вывести всё разрм. Вариант 2 - убедить того, кто сказал вам, что должно быть "идеально", что для ускорения загрузки вашего сайта нужно уменьшить размер html-кода, удалив все ненужные пробелы.

Comment: вам необходимо использовать шаблонизатор. Например https://github.com/twigphp/Twig

Comment: 1. Не делать отступов для РНР года. 2. Ужасно или не ужасно, но вариантов у тебя все равно нет.

Comment: Можно конечно загонять весь вывод в буфер и потом натравливать какой-то внешний форматтер, но по мне вот это как раз и будет кривым решением

Comment: Вопрос: что значит "**понадобилось** сделать, чтобы HTML-код был идеальным"? **Зачем?**

Comment: @АлексейШиманский перфекционизм. Если мне так нравится, значит я буду стараться сделать так, как нравится.

Comment: У вас ничего не выйдет. Потому что даже используя шаблонизаторы будут различного рода отступа, которые они вносят или построение кода через js (даже тот же react или vue, angular), а уж сторонние плагины и подавно - все они в итоге "ломают" идеальную xml структуру. В итоге вам, чтобы добиться идеала, нужно итоговый html каждой страницы заносить в форматтер и уже оттуда весь сайт постранично форматированно публиковать.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а может мне для начала хотя бы множественные пробелы заменить на вызов какой-нибудь своей функции? А то вы прям с плеча рубите.

Comment: @МихаилТестов Это опыт))  Просто я тоже как-то давно хотел так же. Старался, причёсывал. Но есть вещи, которые от тебя не зависят (я перечислял выше фреймворки и плагины, которые вносят в код то, что ты не контролируешь, а так же многое другое...в команде так вообще будет невозможно) и поэтому это просто бесполезно. Да и практического смысла оно не несёт никакого. Пользователю эта красота не нужна, он не смотрит в код, а разрабы делают это на уровне IDE, а не браузера. А мелкие огрехи никого не задевают)) Профи найдут то, что хотят найти.